# Get nearest marker from current location (Android, Google maps)

Tags: android, google-maps

I have retrieved a JSON array that contains different longitudes and latitudes of store branches. I placed it inside a list:

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);
            try {
                Intent mapsIntent = getIntent();
                String jSonArray = mapsIntent.getStringExtra("jsonArray");
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(jSonArray);

                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    Markers branch = new Markers();
                    branch.latitude = Float.parseFloat(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitude"));
                    branch.longitude = Float.parseFloat(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitude"));

                    marker.add(branch);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.d("Error", ex.toString());
            }
        }
```

This is my `Markers` class:

```
 private class Markers {
    public float latitude;
    public float longitude;
}
```

Now I am able to retrieve my current location coordinates using Google maps api v2:

```
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Location");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Now I am wondering, I have my list of store branch locations and my current location then how do I get the nearest store branch from my current location and place a marker on it? I don't understand some implementations that I've seen so it will be of great help if someone teach me how to achieve this. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to sort your markers and use the first element in the sorted array:

```
Collections.sort(marker, new Comparator<Markers>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Markers a, Markers b) {
         Location locationA = new Location("point A");     
         locationA.setLatitude(a.latitude); 
         locationA.setLongitude(a.longitude);
         Location locationB = new Location("point B");
         locationB.setLatitude(b.latitude); 
         locationB.setLongitude(b.longitude);
         float distanceOne = location.distanceTo(locationA);
         float distanceTwo = location.distanceTo(locationB);   
         return Float.compare(distanceOne, distanceTwo);
     }
}
```

Then you have sorted your markers based on the distance to your current location.
After that, use the first element in the marker-Array and add it to your mMap instance.

Comment: Do i put this after my for loop in the onPostExecute method? I've been working on this for about an hour and it still returns me a null value...

Comment: after your for-each stuff, yes. Where do you get a null value?

Comment: Well the problem was not in the sorting itself... I get null values in my locations list as it turned out. Thank you for the answer though. If you're interested here is my other question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42055198/arraylist-element-suddenly-becomes-null)