# ArrayList element suddenly becomes null

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am currently trying to find the nearest store from my current location. I have implemented different methods (i.e: sorting) but to no avail, it only returns me null. It took me a long time to find out what is wrong. Whenever I use `float distance = currPos.distanceTo(locationA);` it yields `0.0`. Upon further checking, I found out that my `locationA` is returning null. I tried accessing `marker.get(0).location` before and after the 2 for loops and the one before the 2 for loops only return a value.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    marker = new ArrayList();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    try {
        jSonArray = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("jsonArray");
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(jSonArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            branch = new Markers();
            Float lat;
            Float lon;
            lat = Float.parseFloat(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitude"));
            lon = Float.parseFloat(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitude"));
            branch.location = new Location("");
            branch.location.setLatitude(lat);
            branch.location.setLongitude(lon);
            marker.add(branch);
        }
        *marker.get(0).location is still accessible here*
        for (int i = 0; i < marker.size(); i++) {
            results[i] = distance(currPos.getLatitude(), currPos.getLongitude(), marker.get(i).location.getLatitude(), marker.get(i).location.getLongitude());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            if (results[i] < results[i + 1]) {
                temp = marker.get(i).location;
            }
        }
    *marker.get(0).location returns null here*
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.d("Error", ex.toString());
}
}
```

Here is the whole activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
private static List<Markers> marker;
private static Markers branch;
private static Location temp;
private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private static Location currPos;
private JSONArray jsonArray;
private double[] results;
private String jSonArray;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    marker = new ArrayList();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    try {
        jSonArray = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("jsonArray");
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(jSonArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            branch = new Markers();
            Float lat;
            Float lon;
            lat = Float.parseFloat(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitude"));
            lon = Float.parseFloat(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitude"));
            branch.location = new Location("");
            branch.location.setLatitude(lat);
            branch.location.setLongitude(lon);
            marker.add(branch);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < marker.size(); i++) {
            results[i] = distance(currPos.getLatitude(), currPos.getLongitude(), marker.get(i).location.getLatitude(), marker.get(i).location.getLongitude());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            if (results[i] < results[i + 1]) {
                temp = marker.get(i).location;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.d("Error", ex.toString());
}
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

private class Markers {
    public Location location;
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    currPos = location;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Location");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
public double distance(double lata, double longa, double latb, double longb) {
    double d2r = Math.PI / 180;
    double dlong = (longa - longb) * d2r;
    double dlat = (lata - latb) * d2r;
    double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dlat / 2.0), 2) + Math.cos(latb * d2r)
            * Math.cos(lata * d2r) * Math.pow(Math.sin(dlong / 2.0), 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double d = 6367 * c;
    return d;

}
```

}

Comment: If the for loops aren't modifying your list, then I don't think you've shown a [mcve]

Comment: Do you have any other threads running at the same time? Where is the declaration of the structure?

Comment: I have updated my post sorry

Comment: "private static List<Markers> marker;" I did not see any assignment. I saw one assignment to the list inside the asynctask

Comment: Your Asynctask is pointless... `doInBackground` is empty

Comment: That was initially inside the asynctask but put it outside to declare it as static in hopes of fixing my problem

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what `static` does or why it would fix the problem

Comment: I would follow @cricket_007 advice, Clean it and see what happens

Comment: I did what @cricket_007 adviced and removed the asynctask and move it on the onCreate method after the first thread but ```marker.get(0).location``` still returns null

Comment: I see you have both `markers` and `marker` as lists. Again, create a *minimal* example and clean up extraneous variables

Comment: I have edited my question again and updated as to what the code looks now after removing the asynctask

Comment: I still haven't found a fix for this one...